# c# - static method having parameters - multi user environments - method result retains or not

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, static, c#-3.0, static-methods

Does static method retain its result when shared across different users ( multi user environment )

*static method*

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<GetEmpResult>> GetEmpResultByEmpId(int? empId, string token)
{
    // api db call..
    // this method does not have cache mechanism..
    // returns Task<IEnumerable<GetEmpResult>> based on the emp id
}
```

If different users access this static method at same time (like multithreading.. It's a web application), whether this static method returns result based on those user's emp id or this method will retain its result (earlier emp result) and returns the same result for the current employee who is hitting this static method next.

OR

in this scenario **without static** is better? Please pour your suggestions. Thank You

Comment: You just updated two lines of comments... I have more questions: How do different users access this method at the same time? Multiprocessing or multithreading? How does this method get invoked? How does this method get its return value? Are the tags c#-4.0 and c#-3.0 related to the question?

Comment: You've said that there's no caching mechanism, so it seems you've answered your own question.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, so static method will retain its result ?

Comment: I have studied that static method will retain its values, but not sure for the method result if accessed in the multi user environment. We can google it to explore further. Thanks :)

Comment: This is completely wrong. A static method doesn't retain any values it calculates or receives. You can use static fields to store information, but that's no different to any other method. If you don't deliberately implement something to store the inputs or result then it won't be retained.

Comment: Note that the comment above was posted on Developer's answer but got migrated here when his answer was deleted.

Comment: OP: Please note that `async` and `await` weren't usable in C# 3.0. With C# 4.0 you could install AsyncCTP to support them, though they weren't officially part of the language until C# 5.0, released in 2012. I'm not sure if you intentionally tagged C# 3.0 and C# 4.0, but it seems likely your code is compiled with a newer version of C# that supports these keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your understanding of static methods is so far, but they aren't so dissimilar to instance methods. A static method is a method that belongs to a class, rather than an instance of the class. This means that a static method can be called without creating an instance of the class. The key difference between a static method and an instance method is that a static method is associated with a class, and an instance method is associated with an instance of a class.

For any method - static or instance - to retain values (parameters, internal values, or results), the developer *must* use some kind of caching mechanism.

As an example, we could use a `ConcurrentDictionary` to store results in a thread-safe way:

```cs
private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, IList<GetEmpResult>> _resultsStore = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IList<GetEmpResult>>();

private static async Task<IEnumerable<GetEmpResult>> GetEmpResultByEmpId(int? empId, string token)
{
    if (_resultsStore.TryGetValue(empId, out var result)) return result;
    
    result = await db.DoSomeCall().ToListAsync(); // api db call to retrieve data
    
    if (_resultsStore.TryAdd(empId, result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    return _resultsStore[empId];
}
```

This might result in multiple calls to the database, so we're assuming the call is read-only and safe to perform multiple times.

As the static method you have shown doesn't have any caching mechanism written into it, it appears that it is not going to retain any values. That being said, the methods your method calls could potentially be storing values, so you might have to look deeper than just this piece of code if you're seeing this kind of behaviour.